# sqlacodegen issue with geometry type

Tags: sqlalchemy, geometry

i'm using sqlacodegen in order to automatically generate model code for SQLAlchemy.

My problem is that I have some columns of type **geometry** and as far as I know, according to the link bellow, sqlacodegen does not support this kind of types.

https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/sqlacodegen/issues/18/did-not-recognize-type-geometry-on

Does anyone know how can I workaround this holdback?
Maybe with the method Mapper or something?

Thnks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you have already figured this out, so this goes to the posterity.

According to the same link you gave ([issue #18](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen/issues/18)), this already has a [PR](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen/commit/c3f51d826078c50865a97fc8130f7b7f1c3cc6b1) to fix it (with no tests though, so it was not accepted as of today).

**Update:** this PR has been merged as of version 2.1.0. Therefore, the below solution---from the original answer---should not be needed anymore. Note that this PR explicitly addressed the support for PostGIS and not MySQL.

---

Nevertheless, the fix is easy. Install [GeoAlchemy2](http://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (it brings PostGIS support to SQLAlchemy) and import it in `sqlacodegen/codegen.py`

```
from sqlalchemy.types import Boolean, String
import sqlalchemy
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
```

Otherwise, ignore those `SAWarnings` and manually fix the geometry types that were not correctly identified, i.e., replace `NullType` with `Geometry`.

```
the_geom = Column(NullType, index=True)
# becomes
the_geom = Column(Geometry(...), index=True)
```

Comment: Somehow I was using `sudo apt install sqlacodegen` (which gave me v1.1.6). I uninstalled with `apt-get remove` and then reinstalled with pip to get v2.1.0+